# How can you retrieve multiple values from Firebase database in cloud functions?

Tags: javascript, java, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following function that I did in Java, it solves my problem, however I want to play with javascript as well. So I had the following problem: I only found functions that retrieve unique values, and I wanted a function similar to `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` that has in Java only that for JavaScript, if not, what would be the alternative?

To understand better, I'll leave the Java code here that works perfectly.

```
mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            float okk = Float.valueOf(ds.child("value").getValue(String.class))/100000000;
                            prov += ds.child("wallet").getValue(String.class)+", "+String.format(Locale.US,"%.8f", okk)+"\n";
                            ds.getRef().removeValue();
                        }
                        tx_array.setText(prov);
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

The output will have to look like this, the same is in java.

> 39Hs93m61zYCaiaNe8yzgrDcutVAz2Kgdc, 0.00151515
>   3QMTHAaYcQB8kJxF5nxxBwskyCFukCNH8t, 0.00151515
>   3AcNSeB9DX3ZKvGxMaec9uZ98rY2BJKuzW, 0.00153787
>   36SjF1MBm2DE6YimNYiy9T4ez6Z7UA4rpg, 0.001540903
>   AHr3GF12div1Kgf6DegeiHSGQYssvbmih, 0.00162121
>   19vR7xchAg1vUgGwATwBsz5NYrVWYKdSQ3, 0.00164545
>   3KmfDgW9RdWp7P2ns3tydXsiChR5U9XKdT, 0.00165757
>   1C8rxppQk8mRSWB8xPKZ5DsYVykJBLNhV3, 0.00166212

Database Struct

[image: Database Struct]

Comment: Can u add the database structure (A screenshot)? As cannot solve what you need from your java code.

Comment: Of course, check my update on post. Thanks!

Comment: I've been able to find the solution. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I read and the user told me, I was able to solve my problem with the following code, which works perfectly as I wanted.

```
exports.showEvent = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    let prov = "";
    return admin.database().ref('requests').once('value', (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach(function(ds) {
          var okk = ds.child("value").val() / 100000000;
          prov += ds.child("wallet").val()+ ", " + parseFloat(okk).toFixed(8) + "\n";
        ds.ref.remove();
      });
        res.send(prov);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you take this piece of Java code:

```
mRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            float okk = Float.valueOf(ds.child("value").getValue(String.class))/100000000;
            prov += ds.child("wallet").getValue(String.class)+", "+String.format(Locale.US,"%.8f", okk)+"\n";
            ds.getRef().removeValue();
```

The equivalent in JavaScript would be:

```
ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(ds) {
        var okk = ds.child("value").val() / 100000000;
        prov += ds.child("wallet").val()+ ", "...
        ds.ref.remove();
    });
});
```

If you run into this type of question more often, I highly recommend reading the [Android documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/) and [Web documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start/) side by side. They both follow the exact same structure, so once you know how to do something in Android, you can easily map it to JavaScript.

Comment: This helped me a lot, it almost worked, but I had to make some modifications to work. But I leave here my thanks!